# Apply Wordpress function on specific woocommerce product categories only

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following function which I need to apply on a particular category only:

```
function ChangeSelectTitle($woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args){
$woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args['show_option_none'] = __('Select your Device/Brand');
return $woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args;
}

if( $product_cat_id == 6 ) {
add_filter('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'ChangeSelectTitle');
}
```

The category ID is 6. I have tried putting `$product_cat_id == 6`to identify the category page but it's not working. How to make it work?

Comment: Where is this code used and where are you getting the variable `$product_cat_id` from?

Comment: This code is being used in the functions file of the active theme and got the variable by seeing the code of another similar plugin.

Comment: By "where are you getting the variable from" I meant where in your code is the variable defined?

Comment: It's not defined, I used it assuming it's a universal variable for wordpress.

Comment: Well there's part of your problem then, because it isn't a global variable. Even if it was, you would have to invoke it using `global $product_cat_id;` before you could use it. Anyway, I suspect you're barking up the wrong tree. The widget args are set before it builds the category list, so you can't hope to effect it like that. Also, the text you're looking to change is displayed when there are no categories to display. The original text is "No product categories exist", so changing it to "Select your Device/Brand" doesn't make sense to me as there's nothing to select!

Comment: On the category page on which I want this function, the sub categories are always there, hence no category being shown won't be an issue. The code is working fine on all pages but I am unable to make it work on a specific category page only (and not all category pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `$product_cat_id` even though it isn't defined anywhere. If you want to know the current category being viewed you need to use `is_product_category(6)`, but you need to use that *inside* the callback function (`ChangeSelectTitle()`), because WordPress hasn't determined whether it's a category archive yet when it runs functions.php.

```
function ChangeSelectTitle($woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args) {
    if ( is_product_category(6) ) {
        $woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args['show_option_none'] = __('Select your Device/Brand');
    }

    return $woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'ChangeSelectTitle');
```